# How to inherit common methods in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inheritance, vue-component, vuex

I have many components which may need to know if the user is an admin or has a certain permission.

Is there any inheritance in Vue.js that allows me to specify a computed method on the uppermost parent, even `App.vue` that has the computed method, then I can just call `hasPermission("...")` from any child and it would work.

Parent:

```
computed: {
      hasPermission(name) {
        return this.$store.getters.hasPermission(name);
      }
}
```

Child:

```
<div v-if="hasPermission('add')"></div>
```

I know I can use Vuex, but that means I have to import `store` in every component, and also make a getter or similar as a computed property of each component. I was just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Does the permission value have to be defined in your store? Otherwise you could try expanding Vue's prototype.
`Vue.prototype.$permission = (name) => { /* your function here */ }`

You can then call `this.$permission(name)` everywhere in your app

Comment: Possibly a good use case for mixins

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mapGetters` [helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) to more easily import getters from your store as computed properties.

For example, in your component:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    // mix the getters into computed with object spread operator
    ...mapGetters([
      'hasPermission',
      // ...
    ])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using vuex, however it is possible by using [provide / inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject).

For example in your main app:

```js
provide: {
    user: {
        admin: true
    }
}
```

And then in child components:

```js
inject: ['user'],

created () {
    console.log(this.user);
}
```